Empty Response from FastAPI Endpoint despite Data in Database in FastAPI
I've created a FastAPI application using SQLAlchemy and Alembic. However, one of my endpoints consistently returns an empty response even though there is data in the database. Upon inspection of the code, I suspect the issue lies within the camera_service.py and camera_repository.py files. The endpoint in question is responsible for querying the database based on certain filters and returning the results as a response. Despite implementing the logic to fetch data from the database and convert it into response objects, the response always contains an empty list of cameras and a count of 0. I need assistance in troubleshooting and resolving this issue to ensure that the endpoint returns the expected data:
response:
{
  "cameras": [],
  "count": 0
}

@router.get('/camera/v1', response_model=AllCamerasResponse, summary="Obter câmera por filtro")
async def search_cameras(
    cam_name: str = None,
    model: str = None,
    is_live_on: bool = False,
    is_live_audio_on: bool = False,
):
    query_filters = {
        "cam_name": cam_name,
        "model": model,
        "is_live_on": is_live_on,
        "is_live_audio_on": is_live_audio_on
    }
    return await camera_service.search_cameras(**query_filters)

class CameraRepository:
    async def get_all_cameras(self, **query_filters):
        async with get_db() as session:
            stmt = select(CameraDB)
            stmt = select(CameraDB).filter_by(**query_filters)
            result = await session.execute(stmt)
            return result.scalars().all()


Firstly, I would ptint SQL statement (add print(stmt)) and run it on database manually to make sure that it returns not empty result

Since you're setting these query filters regardless of whether a value has been submitted - do you have anything that matches cam_name being NULL (None) for example? If you just call the endpoint, you'd expect to get rows where cam_name is NULL and model is NULL and is_live_on is False and is_live_audio_on is False. All filters will have to match (and you're creating stmt twice).
